# When loading an ad video block using RMP VAST, the main stream of the broadcast stops working, how can I get around this?

Tags: javascript, video, vast

I have a video player in which I output the broadcast in m3u8 format (the player uses the hls.js library), I need to load the ad block in the background (for this I use RMP VAST), but the problem is that when the ad block starts loading, the main broadcast immediately dies.

I tried to create a 2 player and upload ads there, but to no avail, I also tried to put the 2 player in an iframe, but that didn't help either. I just have a broadcast on the main player and when it starts loading ads, it just dies. Does anyone have any idea what this is and how to get around it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.